# For loop based on exponential increases

Tags: swift, sorting, for-loop, radix-sort, radix

I am trying to implement a radix sort in Swift (strictly out of boredom).  I have been basing my work thus far on the C/C++ method found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/).

For the most part everything is working as I would expect, except for one for loop which is giving me trouble.

```
for (int exp = 1; max / exp > 0; exp *= 10)
```

Swift no longer allows C style for loops so this won't fly.  I have been trying to recreate the loop using several approaches including this:

```swift
var exp: Int = 1
for _ in (1..<(max / exp)).reversed()
{
    //My code
    exp = exp * 10
}
```

The problem here is `Int` can't contain the size of `exp` after several iterations of the loop.  Since the original loop definition works just fine in Objective-C I believe my complete approach is flawed but I can't see where.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your condition is evaluated only once in your Swift version, with value 1. Use a while cycle instead.

Comment: @MartinR agreed, especially with your non-`Int.max`-overflow addition to the end of you answer.

Comment: Note that your C code does not work correctly for numbers close to `INT_MAX`: `exp *= 10` can overflow even if `max/exp > 0` (which is equivalent to `exp <= max` for positive numbers).

Comment: Based on the solution in the dupe target, e.g. `exp = sequence(first: exp, next: { $0 <= max/10 && 0 < max/$0 ? $0 * 10 : nil}).reduce(0) { $1 }` should solve your C-style -> Swift loop conversion safely.

Comment: @MartinR btw, do you know a neater way to get the last element of a (possibly infinite) sequence? (Say we're only interested in the last, as in this example). We'll need to traverse the elements one by one, by I wonder if there's a better choice than the `reduce` solution above (the only alternative I could come up with was `.map { $0 }.last ?? 0`).

Comment: @dfri: No, I don't. OP did not explicitly state that only the last value is needed. If that is the case then I would probably go with a while-loop, similar to the answer below: `var exp = 1; while 10 * exp <= max { exp *= 10 }`.

Comment: @MartinR Ok, thanks! Minor prompt w.r.t. ninja-edit: in this exponential growth example, that `while` loop should probably use condition `exp <= max/10` though (or overflow for suff. large `max` values, as `10 * exp` is tested once even for the failed test, `> max`).

Comment: @dfri Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: I realize this thread is closed or soon to be, but for the record I used the very simple `while` loop as suggested and it worked great.  I guess after staring at sorting algorithms for a few hours I lost sight of the forest for the trees.  Thanks, guys!